# Docker pass .env value to config folder

Tags: docker, security, elasticsearch, docker-compose

This is my folder structure. I set password but not working. It not reading the value

```
|-docker-vompose.yml
|- .env
|-config
  |- elasticsearch.yml
```

.env

```
ES_PASSWORD=myPassword
```

elasticsearch.yml

```
xpack.security.ssl.password:'${ES_PASSWORD}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  es:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14
    volumes:
      - ./config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

Comment: I have corrected it. But the config file not picking the value. If I put in docker-compose.yml is working

Comment: Can you show us your `docker-compose.yml` file? You would need to have an appropriate entry in the `environment` section of your elasticsearch service.

Comment: Updated docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `docker-compose.yml` to include the appropriate variable declarations in your `environment` section. If you want the variable `ES_PASSWORD` to be exposed inside your elastic search container, you would write:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  es:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14
    environment:
      - "ES_PASSWORD=${ES_PASSWORD}"
    volumes:
      - ./config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

Assuming you have set `ES_PASSWORD` in your `.env` file, this will
pass the value into the container.

This assumes that elasticsearch supports environment variable
interpolation as you have shown in your example.

Comment: I tried it but it was not working. I hard ode in config file can work the password but passing from environment not working

Comment: I also notice why u didn't use - ES_PASSWORD. I use - ES_PASSWORD=

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo on my part. Good catch. With respect to it working or not, you can of course `docker exec` into your container and look to see if the environment variable is set correctly. If it is, then your problem probably has more to do with elasticsearch than it does with docker.